# Multiple Paypal / Braintree accounts changing on shipping method selection

Tags: paypal, magento2, checkout, braintree, payment-method

**Hi everyone.**

We have a customer, whose company is organized in multiple society, so they:

- Have a "brand group name"
- They have many stores in italy grouped in differents companies

**We are trying to solve this situation:**

- When a customer buy on online store, the nearest physical store will be selected as the one who will sell and deliver the products (this part is already solved)
- Depending on the store (and then the company who owns it) the payment method (the paypal or braintree account) has to change so, for example,

  - for shipping in location x will be linked to paypal / braintree account 1
  - for shipping in location y will be linked to paypal / braintree account 2
  - and so on....

**Do u have any suggests on how to solve it?**

We've looked for multiple braintree accounts management, changing the payment method ( or account) dinamically

but we didn't find a solution yet.

any suggest is very appreciated.

thanks everyone for reading and have a nice day :)

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. Your questions might best be answered contacting Braintree [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). I recommend emailing in and referencing this SO question.

Comment: Tanks Hollabaq, i'll send the question to the support

Comment: from braintree support i received a very good assistance but only on what to edit in the braintree accounts.
For Magento2 Implementation they have no experience in specific extensions, so we have to investigate on how to implement. 

Do you ever experienced a similar situation with multiple stores?